# Tensorflow: Batching input queues then changing the queue source

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, tensorflow

I have a model that runs over a set of images and calculates some stats on them using - for simplicity say it just outputs the average image from the set (it does more than that in practice). I have a number of directories that contain images and I want to get the output from each directory. Each directory has a variable number of images in it.

I have constructed the graph, output variable and loss function once for my script. The inputs are batched using slightly adapted [code from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py). I adapted it to take an array of paths which I feed in using a placeholder of variable size. I got the inspiration for that [from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#preloaded-data).

Then I loop over the directories and run the following:

1. Initialize the variables (this resets the previous output variable from the results calculated on the previous directory)
2. Set the image paths variable to the current files array from the new directory: `sess.run(image_paths.initializer, feed_dict={image_paths_initializer: image_paths})`
3. Start the queues running: `queue_threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)`
4. Run for a number of epochs to get results
5. Close threads `coord.request_stop(); coord.join(queue_threads); coord.clear_stop()`
6. Return results, save results, move onto the next directory...

The problem is that when it comes to the second directory the queue runner threads refuse to start (I can see this by debugging the `queue_threads` variable). This gives errors like:

```
Compute status: Aborted: FIFOQueue '_1_input_producer' is closed.
Compute status: Aborted: RandomShuffleQueue '_0_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed.
```

If I don't close the threads (and don't start them a second time) then they don't produce files from the new directory - they ignore the variable assignment op in (2). Is it just not possible to restart the queues like this?

I have tried setting up the queues in their own separate session and pulling the batches from them, but that gives me various CUDA / memory errors. If I do this and add debug stops I can get it to run quite far before it hits this - but I don't know if it is possible to add control dependencies between disjoint sessions/graphs?

It would be possible to start from scratch for each new directory but that adds a lot of overhead to the process that I am trying to avoid. I have done similar things to this (ie, resetting variables and rerunning with different inputs) without queues and it saves a lot of time, so I know that bit works.

Can any of you wonderful SO folk think of a way out of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string_input_producer` is a `FIFOQueue` + `QueueRunner`. You get more control if you use a `FIFOQueue` and enqueue things manually. Something like this

```
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(100, tf.string)
enqueue_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
enqueue_op = filename_queue.enqueue(enqueue_placeholder)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.operation_timeout_in_ms=2000  # for debugging queue hangs
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

sess.run([enqueue_op], feed_dict={enqueue_placeholder:"/temp/dir1/0"})
sess.run([enqueue_op], feed_dict={enqueue_placeholder:"/temp/dir1/1"})

# do stats for /temp/dir1

sess.run([enqueue_op], feed_dict={enqueue_placeholder:"/temp/dir2/0"})
sess.run([enqueue_op], feed_dict={enqueue_placeholder:"/temp/dir2/1"})

# do stats for /temp/dir2

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried to get it working like you say, but it keeps hanging when I try to get the batch. Sounds like this is caused by a queue feeding into another queue (since the `filename_queue` is going into a `shuffle_batch` queue)?

Comment: It will hang either when you are trying to enqueue onto full queue, or dequeue from empty queue. Try "sess.run([filename_queue.size()])" to see how many elements are in the queue already

Comment: Also you need to start queue runners since tf.batch is also a queue

Comment: I think I'm getting there (slowly). My latest stumble was the `FIFOQueue` not cycling the inputs, that seems to be causing it to hang when the shuffle batch is waiting for more entries from an empty queue. Any idea how to get it to cycle?

Comment: You will need to add them manually. IE, if you cycle 100 times, repeat the "sess.run([enqueue_op]).." block 100 times (make sure your queue buffer is big enough or you'll hang MainThread)

Comment: Massive thanks for your help on pointing me in the right direction. I have added my final solution as another answer here. I did away with the queue runners entirely in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Big thanks to @yaroslav-bulatov for pointing me in the right direction on this.

It seems that my biggest problem was with the queue runners. When I replaced the filename queue with a `FIFOQueue` and manually enqueued filenames to it that worked fine, but because I was also using a `shuffle_batch` queue this got upset when I tried to empty the filenames queue for the next directory. I could not empty this queue either as it causes lockups or breaks the queue, so the best I could manage was to let it fill up with the new images while keeping the leftovers from the previous directory - obviously no good! In the end I replaced that with a `RandomShuffleQueue` and again enqueue items manually in the same way as with filenames. I think this is giving good-enough mixing of images and isn't overkill for the problem. No threading, but as soon as I did away with that things got a lot simpler.

I've included my final solution as below. Any suggestions welcome!

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

output_dir = '/my/output/dir'

my_dirs = [
    [
        '/path/to/datasets/blacksquares/black_square_100x100.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/blacksquares/black_square_200x200.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/blacksquares/black_square_300x300.png'
    ],
    [
        '/path/to/datasets/whitesquares/white_square_100x100.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/whitesquares/white_square_200x200.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/whitesquares/white_square_300x300.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/whitesquares/white_square_400x400.png'
    ],
    [
        '/path/to/datasets/mixedsquares/black_square_200x200.png',
        '/path/to/datasets/mixedsquares/white_square_200x200.png'
    ]
]

# set vars
patch_size = (100, 100, 1)
batch_size = 20
queue_capacity = 1000

# setup filename queue
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(
    capacity=queue_capacity,
    dtypes=tf.string,
    shapes=[[]]
)
filenames_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype='string', shape=(None))
filenames_enqueue_op = filename_queue.enqueue_many(filenames_placeholder)

# read file and preprocess
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
uint8image = tf.image.decode_png(file)
cropped_image = tf.random_crop(uint8image, patch_size) # take a random 100x100 crop
float_image = tf.div(tf.cast(cropped_image, tf.float32), 255) # put pixels in the [0,1] range

# setup shuffle batch queue for training images
images_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(
    capacity=queue_capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=0,  # allow queue to become completely empty (as we need to empty it)
    dtypes=tf.float32,
    shapes=patch_size
)
images_enqueue_op = images_queue.enqueue(float_image)

# setup simple computation - calculate an average image patch
input = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,) + patch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
avg_image = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.5, size=patch_size).astype(np.float32))
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.sub(avg_image, input))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2.).minimize(loss)

# start session and initialize variables
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# note - no need to start any queue runners as I've done away with them

for dir_index, image_paths in enumerate(my_dirs):
    image_paths_cycle = cycle(image_paths)

    # reset the optimisation and training vars
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    num_epochs = 1000
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        # keep the filename queue at capacity
        size = sess.run(filename_queue.size())
        image_paths = []
        while size < queue_capacity:
            image_paths.append(next(image_paths_cycle))
            size += 1
        sess.run(filenames_enqueue_op, feed_dict={filenames_placeholder: image_paths})

        # keep the shuffle batch queue at capacity
        size = sess.run(images_queue.size())
        while size < queue_capacity:
            sess.run([images_enqueue_op])
            size += 1

        # get next (random) batch of training images
        batch = images_queue.dequeue_many(batch_size).eval()

        # run train op
        _, result, loss_i = sess.run([train_op, avg_image, loss], feed_dict={input: batch})
        print('Iteration {:d}. Loss: {:.2f}'.format(i, loss_i))

        # early stopping :)
        if loss_i < 0.05:
            break

    # empty filename queue and verify empty
    size = sess.run(filename_queue.size())
    sess.run(filename_queue.dequeue_many(size))
    size = sess.run(filename_queue.size())
    assert size == 0

    # empty batch queue and verify empty
    size = sess.run(images_queue.size())
    sess.run(images_queue.dequeue_many(size))
    size = sess.run(filename_queue.size())
    assert size == 0

    # save the average image output
    result_image = np.clip(result * 255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    with open(os.path.join(output_dir, 'result_' + str(dir_index)), 'wb') as result_file:
        result_file.write(tf.image.encode_png(result_image).eval())

print('Happy days!')
exit(0)
```

This ouputs `result_0` - a black square, `result_1` - a white square and `result_2` - a (mostly) grey square.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your own answer, I would suggest you to take a look at [`tf.train.match_filenames_once`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/match_filenames_once). It allows you to specify the pattern for your files and pass it to [string_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer).

```
q = tf.train.string_input_producer(
  tf.train.match_filenames_once('/path/to/datasets/*.png')
)
```

Here is a more [comprehensive example](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f). By doing this not only you will fix your problem, but also will not need to iterate over all your directories.